# Problems converting SQL-Server code to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, cursor, sp-send-dbmail

I have the following code slightly modified from a SQL-Server version. I need help converting it to MySQL. At present I get the error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server near DECLARE @first_n' at line 1".

```
DECLARE 
@out_desc AS VARCHAR(1000),
@out_mesg AS VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE @first_name AS VARCHAR(50),
@email AS NVARCHAR(50),
@body AS NVARCHAR(200)

DECLARE @birth_date AS DATETIME

DECLARE C1 CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT first_name, birth_date, email
FROM emp_master

OPEN C1
FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
@first_name, @birth_date, @email
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  IF DATEPART(DAY,@birth_date) = DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE())
  AND DATEPART(MONTH,@birth_date) = DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())
  BEGIN
    SET @body = '<b>Happy Birthday ' + @first_name +
    '</b><br />Many happy returns of the day'
    + '<br /><br />Customer Relationship Department'
    EXEC sp_send_mail
    'pradeep.y@csmsoftware.com',
    @email,
    'Birthday Wishes',
    @body,
    'htmlbody',
    @output_mesg = @out_mesg output,
    @output_desc = @out_desc output

    PRINT @out_mesg
    PRINT @out_desc
  END
  FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
  @name, @birthdate, @email
END
CLOSE C1
DEALLOCATE C1
```

Comment: please let me know about it, i am not getting solved this, thanks

Comment: Please don't use `[oracle]` tag for questions about MySQL. They are two different database products. The fact that Oracle Corporation now owns MySQL is irrelevant when asking questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: This is Ms Sql Server syntax and functions. Not mysql!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're going to MySQL, you need to a terminator for each statement. This is usually a semi-colon. So for example your first statement would become:

```
DECLARE
@out_desc AS VARCHAR(1000),
@out_mesg AS VARCHAR(100);
#------ look here -------^
```

Also, while the other aspects of your code may be fine (I haven't checked, and rarely use cursors), it would make sense to filter what you insert into the cursor rather than have the following​ condition within the while loop

```
IF DATEPART(DAY,@birth_date) = DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE())
AND DATEPART(MONTH,@birth_date) = DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())
```

Though there are similarities, some SQL-Server code is quite different to MySQL. In particular, I don't think the `sp_send_mail` is valid and I don't think the MySQL "equivalent" is at all similar.

I'm not in a position to provide further help translating this from sql-server syntax to MySQL. You need to go through your code line by line and search for the MySQL equivalents of any bits that don't work. Add a section at a time and see if the code will run without errors. When you get errors run a Google search for "MySQL equivalent of SQL-server X" where X is whatever thing isn't working.

Also in case it manages to send email when perhaps you weren't quite expecting it, don't use the intended recipients email addresses until you're confident all the bugs have been ironed out. Hard code that to your own email address (in the select into the `CURSOR`, so you can see that the associated part inside the `WHILE` loop is working.

Comment: i wanted to send email to the employees in the company for their birthday wishes through, but in mysql i was not getting any methods to send email, so that i came for this solution

Comment: if i am adding semicolon (;) at the end of the statement again i am getting more errors

Comment: by two days i am sticking on this, please give me a solution

Comment: I've added some guidance to my answer. You also _may_ get more help here from others if you re-title your question to "Problems converting this procedure to MySQL syntax from sql-server", I'd also suggest some additional tags: `sql-server`, `cursor` and `sp_send_dbmail` (I know that last one doesn't quite match, but it's the available tag).

Comment: I've submitted an edit to that effect on your behalf. It's won't show until peer reviewed ... when it may not be approved anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to correct this

```
     FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
    @name, @birthdate, @email
```

to

```
 FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
  @first_name, @birth_date, @email
```

@name, @birthdate are not declared

Comment: i replaced the variables then also that error has not resolved

Comment: by two days i am stuck on this please give me solution

Comment: I am not getting any syntax error after I modified the variable names. However the results won't appear incase your if statement conditions are not met.

Comment: this is how i modified    'FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
first_name, birth_date, email'

Comment: with at symbol(@)

Comment: I am talking about the last fetch statement before end

Comment: Have you changed the first fetch or the last fetch statement. First fetch statement is correct. Last one should be corrected.

Comment: yes i have changed both at first and at last too, but then also the error is not getting solved